# Hide/Change title-view of android ExpandableListView while showing the content-view

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I was using [this library](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)'s ExpandableListItemAdapter & the result is as usual. But I need to change as well as **hide** the **title-view** while showing the **content-view** just like [these pictures](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fvnoranp194q5m2/AAD33TYOUzUUcFHfU2n-tgdea?dl=0).

Can anyone please guide me how to do it ASAP?
If it's not possible with the library, it won't be a problem to switch to any other view.

Thank you.

**NB:** My actual view is quite complex than this simple *TextView vs. ImageView*,  but I think this'll be enough to demonstrate my problem.

*PS: I wanted to post the images & my tried articles here, but SO's not allowing me due to lack of my reputation. **Sorry** for any inconvenience for this "page-routings".*

Comment: Can you post just a snippet of code, and maybe some LogCat errors, if any?

Comment: My code isn't anything different than the [provided library's sample here](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/tree/master/example)
And I don't have any error, rather I wanna change the view as the pictures linked.